# Multiple returns for IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWlMZ.png)

I'm trying to use and if statement to return a possible 3 different values. I'm trying to determine if a customer re-ordered this year after ordering last year.

My results should be re-ordered, only 2018 or Q4 not Q1. My formula is : =IF(AND(I15>0,J15<1),"Q4 not Q1","Re-Ordered")

But as you can see I'm not sure if I should be adding an or statement or what the layout of the formula should be. Any help is greatly appreciated. Everything I've found on this keeps returning my statement as false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IF statement can only return 2 values, so if you want to return 3, you have to nest it inside another IF like this:

`=IF(A=B,"A equals B",IF(A=C, "A equals C", "A does not equal B and A does not equal C"))`

Based on your screenshot:

`=IF(AND(I12>0,J12<1),"Q4 not Q1",IF(AND(I12>0,J12>0),"Re-Ordered","2018 Only"))`

Comment: Sorry, missed your screenshot, you don't need the last `IF` unless you want need to account for another scenario to filter out, like 2017 only.